# Detect resize and execute code at X resolution in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the following:

1. Detect page width on load and add/remove class if it's below/above 959px
2. If I resize the page I want to do the same

```js
$(window).on("resize load", function(e) {
   e = $("body").width();
   if (e <= 959) { 
      $("#button").addClass("active")
   }
   if (e >= 960) {
      $("#button").removeClass("active")
   }
})
```

This code works, but it removes the active class even if I resize the window from 500px to 501px. **I want that to only add the class if I go above 960px or remove it if I go below 959px.** How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers! In the meantime I figured out a solution that works and suit my needs.

```
$(window).one("load", function () {
    r = $("body").width();
    if (r >= 960) {
        $("body").attr("mobile","0")
        //do something
    }
    if (r <= 959) {
        $("body").attr("mobile","1")
        //do something
    }
});

$(window).on("resize", function() {
    r = $("body").width();
    if ($("body").attr("mobile") == "0") {
        if (r <= 959) { 
            //do something
            $("body").attr("mobile","1")
        }
    }   
    if ($("body").attr("mobile") == "1") {
        if (r >= 960) { 
            //do something
            $("body").attr("mobile","0")
        }   
    }
})
```

**Explanation:**

It's a very specific solution since I modify the tabindex values in mobile view and I don't want to change these values back to 0 on a simple resize, only in the case I switch from mobile view to desktop.

Comment: What if the window is 959?

Comment: you forgot to handle what happens if width is exactly `959`

Comment: Why not just use media queries?

Comment: After the edit, it is the same thing as before..... equal should be on one or the other.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I added <= and >=.
@epascarello: I want to do other things too. Add/remove tabindex attribute, etc.

Comment: And that code adds the class and than deletes the class, just use else, no reason for another if. And using `e` seems bad since that is the event object in the arguments above.

Comment: `$("#button").toggleClass("active", $("body").width()<=959)`

Comment: But how I can make it work on window resize?

Comment: @macc run that same code on resize?

Comment: consider window.matchMedia (the javascript implementation of media queries) instead of resize event.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the `window` is different than the width of the `body`.  Using `$('body').width()` will account for the overflow, whereas using `$(window).width()` will give you the actual screen width.

```javascript
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
  $('#button').toggleClass('active', $(this).width() <= 959)
});
```

However, using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) is much more straight forward if in fact, you are just adding CSS properties.

```css
#button {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

@media (max-width: 959px) {
  #button {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could ouse window.matchMedia for this. If you look at the [perf](https://jsperf.com/matchmedia-vs-resize/3) test, matchMedia is a lot faster than resize.

```
var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width:959px)");

// onload
setButton(mql);

// add listener for the query
mq.addListener(setButton);

function setButton(mq) {
    if (mql.matches) {
        // do something with your setButton
    } else {
        // no match....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/hLkv1xan/1/

```js
$(window).on("resize load", function(e) {
   e = $("body").width();
   if (e <= 959) {
      $("#button").addClass("active")
   } else {
      $("#button").removeClass("active")
   }
});
```

```css
.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">
Submit
</button>
```

I just modified your code a bit, change in the condition.

Hope this will help you.